# Java HashSet and HashMap JBoss-RMI Serialization exception with OpenJDK-1.8.0-312

Tags: java, serialization, jboss, rmi

Since I installed openjdk-1.8.0-312 patch I got this error in all JBoss-RMI invocations that use `HashMap` and `HashSet`.

This is using openjdk-1.8.0 and running JBoss as 6.1.1:

```
2022-05-05 10:30:19,761 ERROR [STDERR]  ... 100 more
2022-05-05 10:30:19,761 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: org.jboss.serial.exception.SerializationException: Excepted to be String
2022-05-05 10:30:19,761 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.DataContainer$DataContainerInput.readUTF(DataContainer.java:1120)
2022-05-05 10:30:19,761 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.serial.persister.ObjectInputStreamProxy.readUTF(ObjectInputStreamProxy.java:196)
2022-05-05 10:30:19,761 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.FieldsContainer.readField(FieldsContainer.java:147)
2022-05-05 10:30:19,761 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.serial.objectmetamodel.FieldsContainer.readMyself(FieldsContainer.java:218)
2022-05-05 10:30:19,761 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.serial.persister.ObjectInputStreamProxy.readFields(ObjectInputStreamProxy.java:224)
2022-05-05 10:30:19,761 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.util.HashSet.readObject(HashSet.java:298)
2022-05-05 10:30:19,763 ERROR [STDERR]  ... 104 more
2022-05-05 10:30:19,763 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
```

Has anyone gotten this error? Any clue on how to solve this (without removing HashSet and HashMap from methods)?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the patch at both server and client? If not, do.

Comment: Yes. These RMI calls are between 2 EAR's running on the same JBOSS instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching back to previous versions of openjdk.